# FileOutputStream not properly writing non-.txt files

Tags: java, networking, fileoutputstream

For some reason my FileOutputStream is only properly writing files that are in the .txt format. The bytes are being received from another server via UDP, but it is over the localhost so I don't think the packets are being lost. Can anyone see what would be causing non .txt bytes to be written poorly? Do you think the problem is possibly from the server sending the bytes. I would be surprised if it was from the sending server though because it writes exactly the right bytes for the .txt file.

```
public class CompressionServer {

private static final int ECHOMAX = 65535;  // Maximum size of UDP packet

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int servPort = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(servPort);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[ECHOMAX], ECHOMAX);

    for (;;) {  // Run forever, receiving and echoing datagrams
        socket.receive(packet);
        byte[] data = packet.getData();
        String fileName = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength());

        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(fileName.trim()); //unzipped file output
        FileOutputStream fout2 = new FileOutputStream(fileName.trim() + ".zip"); //zipped file output
        ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(fout2); //I guess this writes zip bytes to fout2?

        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName.trim()); //call the entry in the zip file "proj3.bin"
        zout.putNextEntry(entry); //the next entry our ZipOutputStream is going to write is "proj3.bin"

        while(true) {
            socket.receive(packet);
            data = packet.getData();
            String magicString = new String(data, 0, packet.getLength(), "US-ASCII");
            int index = magicString.indexOf("--------MagicStringCSE283Miami");
            if(index != -1){
                fout.write(data, 0, index);
                fout.flush();
                fout.close();

                zout.write(data, 0, index); //write the byteBuffer's data to the client via the zip output stream
                zout.flush(); //push all data out of the zipOutputStream before continuing
                fout2.flush();
                zout.close();
                fout2.close();
                break;
            }
            //System.out.println("packet received");
            fout.write(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
            fout.flush();

            zout.write(data, 0, packet.getLength()); //write the byteBuffer's data to the client via the zip output stream
            zout.flush(); //push all data out of the zipOutputStream before continuing
            fout2.flush();
        }   
    }
    //socket.close();
}
/* NOT REACHED */
}
```

Comment: The Debugger is your friend. it is possible the string conversion is losing bytes. Is `magicString.length() == data.length` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> FileOutputStream not properly writing non-.txt files

It certainly isn't a problem with `FileOutputStream`. It writes whatever you tell it to write. However there are too many ways you could have corrupted the data before getting anywhere near the `FileOutputStream:`

1. You haven't shown the sending code.
2. `String` is not a container for binary data.
3. 'From another server' and 'over the localhost' are mutually contradictory, and neither of them assures delivery of UDP datagrams, or non-duplication, or sequencing. This is not going to work correctly without an ACK- or NACK-based protocol.
4. The maximum *payload* size of a UDP datagram is 65507 bytes, which is still wildly impractical. The generally accepted *usable* maximum is 534 bytes.
5. Flushing and closing `fout2` when you have already flushed or closed `zout` is redundant, and flushing `zout` before closing is is also redundant.